# How to change targetSandboxVersion in production update?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-vision

I updated my production app with `targetSandboxVersion="2"` because the Google Play Console wouldn't let me release my instant app without that. Come to find out, that was a bug that was fixed by the Play Console team. A Google engineer mentioned, in another thread, that not only is this no longer required but it is discouraged but in order for me to have released the instant app I had no choice at the time not knowing it was a bug.

The issue is now I have an app with `targetSandboxVersion="2"` on the Play Store and downloaded by thousands of people but come to find out this inadvertently broke Google's Mobile Vision library on Oreo devices. I get the the following logcat repeating nonstop:

> I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so
>   I/Vision: libbarhopper.so library load status: false
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module  com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
>   I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101

So now I want to revert back to `targetSandboxVersion="1"` (really just removing `targetSandboxVersion` from the installed manifest altogether) but the app can't be installed on top of an apk with `targetSandboxVersion="2"`.

What do I do? Is there any way to change the manifest in this way allowing a seamless update?

Comment: Josh, can you please elaborate on Mobile Vision API issues you are getting?

Comment: I get the the following logcat repeating nonstop.

----I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so
----I/Vision: libbarhopper.so library load status: false
----W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
----I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
----I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101

Comment: When I remove targetSandboxversion from the installed manifest the library works like normal and I no longer get this output

Answer (score 2):

> *So now I want to revert back to targetSandboxVersion="1" (really just removing targetSandboxVersion from the installed manifest altogether) but the app can't be installed on top of an apk with targetSandboxVersion="2".*

Unfortunately, currently there is no easy way for a seamless downgrade from `targetSandboxVersion` 2 down to 1.

The user will have to uninstall the app version that’s running on sandbox 2 in order to install one with a lower sandbox version.

As for the issue with the Google’s Mobile Vision library, I would suggest you to create a sample project that fails with this library and submit it to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787